# Computer groups in OMS - How to add new computer to existing group in OMS?

Tags: azure, oms

I have created computer group by saving results from **LOG SEARCH** in OMS

[image]

Now I want to add new computer to the group. But I do not see **EDIT** option in saved computer group.

I see only option to **delete** and **recreate** the group from Log Search. Is my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see only option to delete and recreate the group from Log Search. Is
>   my understanding is correct?

Yes, you are right. For now, Azure does not support to edit computer group. **If you want to modify the group, please create a new group with the same Category and Name to overwrite the original group.**

More information about managing computer groups please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-computer-groups#managing-computer-groups).

Update: You could get group name and category name on OMS Portal.

[image]

Comment: where I can see category name of existing group?

Comment: You could check group name `category name:group name`